# How to copy a file from one sharepoint to another?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm trying to copy a specific file from a Sharepoint folder to another. The main problem is that I have read only access in the Sharepoint where the file is living and I'm just able to download it (The other Sharepoint where I need to copy the file, I'm owner).I've been trying to use power automate or logic apps (Azure). Unfortunately I'm not getting closer to the goal, my flows configuration and tries as follow:

1st Try: My attempt was simple, is just a workflow that is focused on copy a file to one Sharepoint to other. My option was use "Get File Metadata" step to get " File Identifier" and use this variable in the "Copy File" step:

[image]

2nd Try: This option was focused on get list content and then, filter the file need it. Unfortunately I'm not able to get identifier:

[image]

What would be the proper way to copy the file if I just have read access to the Sharepoint where the file is living? How can I to create File Identifier Manually? Is there any option available in Power Automate instead logic Apps?

Answer (score 0):

> How to copy a file from one sharepoint to another?

You can copy files using Logic apps/ Power Automate, only if you have permissions to list the folders in SharePoint otherwise you cannot.

> What would be the proper way to copy the file if I just have read access to the Sharepoint where the file is living?

The **`design`** you have used is right in PowerAutomate/ Logic Apps:

[image]

If you have permissions then only you can copy file when you have file identifier.